# Cocos2d-x Create sprite not successful

Tags: runtime, cocos2d-x

I have Board class:

```
struct Cell
{
    cocos2d::Sprite* sprite;
    int status;
};

class Board
{
public:
    Cell* cells[5][5];
    ...
};
```

In .cpp file, I call:

```
cells[i][j]->sprite = Sprite::create("abc.png");
```

but error runtime.
Please tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating Sprite you have to retain it if you are not adding it to Layer in function where you have create otherwise it will be released after function call.
you should use like

```
cells[i][j]->sprite = Sprite::create("abc.png");
sprite->retain();
```

in destructor release it:

```
cells[i][j]->sprite->release();
```

Comment: Thank for answer but it unresolved issues. When I use Sprite* cells[5][5]; and call cells[i][j] = Sprite::create("abc.png"); is OK but I want to use Cell* cells[5][5]; How it is?

Comment: Runtime error just jump into function: cells[i][j]->sprite = Sprite::create("abc.png");

Comment: Share full code. I don't understand what you are trying.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I forget allocation for cell[i][j], hic.